# In Solidity Language, what happens when a function with given parameters on different contracts but different types of data stored for Interface?

Tags: interface, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

For Solidity Programing Language,
While defining **Interface**, we name it as per our needs and then call it as needed with the same types of inputs.

What happens when there are the same function names with the same parameter names but different types of data stored?

Eg. Here are two different contracts stored on Ethereum Blockchain separately. What will happen if while writing a 3rd smart contract, I create an interface and call function with name "favoriteNumber". Which value will it return? 10 or 15?

```
contract A {
 uint randomnumber = 10;
 function favoriteNumber (uint _number) public view returns(uint randomnumber) {
 }
}

contract B {
 uint randomnumber = 15;
 function favoriteNumber (uint _number) public view returns(uint randomnumber) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depends on what contract you call, each contract have it unique address with each own storage